# Call a function that returns an array in the src property

Tags: gruntjs

I have a Grunt task that requires the `src` property to be built by calling a function that returns an array. However, the return value is ignored when more than one item is returned from the array.

I've boiled the issue down to its most simple form. Lets say I have a function, `getItems` that simply returns an array of two strings (files in the project).

```
getItems: function() {
  return ['build/file1.js', 'build/file2.js'];
}
```

Lets say we want to call this function in the `src` property of the `clean` task.

```
clean: {
  items: ['<%= getItems() %>', 'build/file3.js']
}
```

Calling `clean:items` does *not* remove `build/file1.js` or `build/file2.js` (but does remove `build/file3.js`) from the project. Why not?

It's worth noting that this behavior exists in *any* task, not just `clean`. I simply used `clean` for demonstration purposes.

**However**, if I return just *one* item from the `getItems` function, the `clean` task will remove it.

```
// the following removes build/file1.js and build/file3.js from the project

getItems: function() {
  return ['build/file1.js'];
}

clean: {
  items: ['<%= getItems() %>', 'build/file3.js']
}
```

It's also worth noting that using *only* the `getItems` function does not work either when it returns more than one item.

```
// the following does not remove build/file1.js or build/file2.js

getItems: function() {
  return ['build/file1.js', 'build/file2.js'];
}

clean: {
  items: '<%= getItems() %>'
}
```

Why can't I call a function that returns an array with more than one item from within the `src` property of any arbitrary task?

Comment: It looks like you're putting an array inside the array when you do that... Does it work to do `items: ('<% getItems() %>').concat(['build/file3.js'])`? That would concatenate the two arrays instead of nesting them.

Answer (score 1):

I tried for awhile to get this to work when the function is defined in `grunt.initConfig` and had no luck.

Is there anything stopping you from just defining it before your initConfig though?

You could do this:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // define the function outside of the config
  var getItems = function() {
    return ['build/file1.js', 'build/file2.js'];
  };

  grunt.initConfig({

    clean: {
      items: getItems()
    }

  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
};
```

Then if you wanted file3.js on there as well just concat:

```
clean: {
  items: getItems().concat(['build/file3.js'])
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I'll leave the issue open to see if someone knows why the original code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

jshanley's answer is exactly what I was going to suggest to solve your problem.

The reason `getItems` function works when it is returning a single item in an array is because whatever is returned by the function is returned as a string, since you are invoking the function through template string.

To see this, you can try:

```
grunt.registerTask('debug', function () {
    console.log(grunt.template.process('<%= getItems() %>'));
});
```

When getItems function returns one item in an array:

```
getItems: function () {
    return ['test3'];
}
```

Running `grunt debug`, returns

```
Running "debug" task
test3

Done, without errors.
```

When getItems function return multiple items in an array:

```
getItems: function () {
    return ['test3', 'test4'];
}
```

Running `grunt debug`, returns

```
Running "debug" task
test3,test4

Done, without errors.
```

Therefore when your config looked like:

```
clean: {
    items: ['<%= getItems() %>', 'build/file3.js']
}
```

It was consumed by `grunt-contrib-clean` plugin as:

```
clean: {
    items: ['build/file1.js,build/file2.js', 'build/file3.js']
}
```

Which is not the desired behaviour.

Comment: Oh that's interesting, I didn't realize it just made it into a string. That makes much more sense now. Thanks.